# Making an app available only to sim capable devices

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to allow only installation of an android app to a sim capable devices in Google Play?
[Distributing to Specific Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html) does not seem to explain this.

Comment: There's a way through which you can check a device supports Sim or not but After the installation

Answer (score 0):

put a check when your app gets open for the first time

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);     
String simID = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
//do logic stuff
```

use this, with a BroadcastReceiver with BOOT_COMPLETED.
Easy stuff, go ahaed

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to look for the telephony (`android.hardware.telephony`) [uses-feature](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html).

Comment: I have read about the `uses-feature` but I have yet to test it. Does this really filter out devices which are not possessing a particular `required` hardware based on your experience?